# C# Marshall void* that is set to NULL

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling

Trying to write a wrapper for a C DLL.

The C Native signature is:

```
BOOL WINAPI PBM_OpenCard (DWORD* CardHandle, TCHAR* CardName, void* Module, 
        DWORD ModuleId, WORD ShareFlags, WORD LoadFlags)
```

To which documentation says: "`Module` set to `NULL` - reserved"

This what my c# signature looks like:

```
public static extern  bool PBM_OpenCard(ref uint CardHandle,
        StringBuilder CardName, System.IntPtr Module, uint ModuleId,
        ushort ShareFlags, ushort LoadFlags)
```

What do i pass in for the Module argument in my C# App? I tried using `System.IntPrt.Zero` and it compiled, but not sure if that is the right way to do it since I can't interface with the hardware at this point.

Comment: Why StringBuilder? Isn't CardName an in param?

Comment: CardName is the name of the card I pass in to the function. Its a windows registry value. It should be just a string? P/invoke assistant actually sets it as a System.IntPrt which it didnt make much sense to me.

Comment: Should be declared as `string` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, `IntPtr.Zero` does correspond to C's `NULL`, just don't forget to set your .NET build away from `AnyCPU` to match the arch of the native method you're linking with.

Protip: Use the `[return: MarshalAs]` attribute syntax to set the marshalling of `BOOL` to `System.Boolean` (though this is the default, it helps to be explicit). the same applies to your parameters as I see it's using `TCHAR` (which makes me die inside).

Protip 2: Don't forget to modify the method signature to conform to .NET style conventions, including not using underscores in identifiers, `PascalCase` for publics and using `camelCase` parameter names. Also consider hiding native methods from all consumers and wrapping them in a safe `IDisposable` object.

Comment: Pro tip 1 is wrong. Default bool marshalling is a 4 byte bool, perfect for native BOOL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I said that `BOOL`/`Boolean` marshaling is the default, but I personally recommend always putting the `MarshalAs` attribute.

Comment: I know what you said, but it is wrong, or at best vague and misleading. `bool` is an alias of `System.Boolean` and marshals as `UnmanagedType.Bool`, a 4 byte boolean.

Comment: Regarding your protip 2: It's worth mentioning that if you rename your C# extern method's name, you need to add `EntryPoint = "<C function name>"` to the `DllImport` attribute.